# Ударение в словах "Росия" в прошлые века

Tags: фонетика

Где  ставилось  ударение  в  словах  Русия, Росия, Россия  в  15 - 16 веках ?

Comment: Действительно, по  15-му  веку  письменных  материалов  нет. Но  впервые  на  русском  языке  в  1517 году  в  Московской  грамоте (  Словарь  Фасмера  ).  С  двойным  "с".  Как  и  в  греческом  того  времени.  Уже  в  таком  виде  имя  страны  присутствует  в  титуле  Фёдора  Иоанновича, затем  у  Лжедмитрия,  а  от  Алексея  Михайловича  -  до  1917-го. Думаю,  что  и  ударение  и  двойное "с" -  грецизм  с  пятивековым  стажем.

Comment: О двойном С можно спорить (у Фасмера, напрмер, фиксация, не норма), но это не вопрос ударения.  
Как можно мз письменных источников выводить кдарение - непонятно.
Вот насчет греческого "того времени" - это дейтвительно интересно. 
Сейчас там одно С: Ρωσία. 
В греческом изменилось написание? Когда, почему? Я ничего о таком не слышал.

Comment: Давно  ли  в  русском  языке  появилась  норма ? Думаю, что  и  в  греческом  тоже. Греческих  текстов  16  века  не  читал,  доверяю  спциалисту, а  Фасмер - эллинист.  В  современном  греческом  "с"  одно  и  ударение  на  "и".  А  в  современном  русском  в  названиях  стран  на  "ия"  ударение  падает  на  предыдущий  слог.  Россия  смотрится  исключением.  И  с  двойным  "с"  ситуация  схожая.  Следовательно  это  давняя  дипломатическая, канцелярская  форма,  закреплённая  традицией.

Comment: А если нет нормы в ударении, то о чем вообще можно спрашивать в данном вопросе?  
Фасмер - славист. Про его элиинский бэкграуд мне ничего не известно. Но это не имеет отношения к вопросу.  
Я не понял сути. На основании чего вы утверждаете, что в греческом "Россия" писалась с удвоенным СС (я видел некие источники, утверждающие то же самое, но ни одного документально подтвержденного случая там не называлось)? И главное - еогда и почему изменилоась это написание?

Comment: О  том, что  Фасмер - эллинист, я  прочитал  в  книге  В.В. Виноградова  "История  слов".  Написание  слова  Россия  колебалось  ещё  два  века - Россия,  Росия,  Русия,  Руссия,  пока  не  закрепилось  в  18-м  веке.  Ваша  версия,  почему  это  произошло,  мне  нравится.  Я  думаю,  что  ударение  тоже  не  сразу  устоялось.  Недаром  в  народном  Расея  под  ударением  "е".  Норма  в  ударении  есть.  Здесь  она  нарушена,  но  закреплена  традицией.

Comment: А  о  том,  что  в  неофициальном  порядке  ударение  могло  быть  на  корне  вы  и  сами  допускаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "Россия" введено в оборот при Петре. До того обычным было "Русь". Поэтому говоритить о месте ударения до XVII века не совсем корректно.
В "неофициальном порядке" можно предположить, что где-то могло использоваться Р**о**сия или Р**у**сия для обозначения земель Московского княжества и/или Московской Руси (не ранее XVI века). Смещение ударения на флексию в тот период маловероятно. Но могло существовать и народное "Рос**е**я", о чем свидетельствует Фасмер. Хотя думаю, последнее все-таки гораздо более позднее образование.